# List every Cognito user

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I want to list for every user cognito the list of groups he belong make all information in a dictionary and convert it to a json format but I don't now where is the problem?

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
    UserPool_Id = "eu-west-1_NxL8iQjim"
    List_Group_Name = list()
    dicti = {}

    # On recupère la liste de tout les utilisateurs
    try:
        response = client.list_users(
            UserPoolId=UserPool_Id,
        )
    except:
        print ("Error message")

    response = client.list_users(
            UserPoolId=UserPool_Id
        )

    i = len(response["Users"])


    while (i>0):
        #pour chaque utilisateur
        for user in response["Users"]:

            dicti["Users"][i]["UserName"]=user["Username"]

            response2 = client.admin_list_groups_for_user(
                Username=user["Username"],
                UserPoolId=UserPool_Id
            )

            List_Group_Name=list()
            for group in  response2["Groups"]:
                List_Group_Name.append(group["GroupName"])

            dicti["Users"][i]["UserName"]=List_Group_Name
        i=i-1

    return(dicti)
```

Comment: Is it working? What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: a have that kind of error:

Comment: Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "'Users'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      30,
      "lambda_handler",
      "dicti[\"Users\"][i][\"UserName\"]=user[\"Username\"]"
    ]
  ]
}

Request ID:
"1de45315-af74-11e8-a5bc-7b1ba9bf8c01"

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to initialise dictionary inside dictionary as per below. Kindly note that `time.sleep` function is added in between to avoid `TooManyRequestsException` from AWS. Hope it helps.

```
try:
    response = client.list_users(
        UserPoolId=UserPool_Id,
    )
except:
    print ("Error message")

response = client.list_users(
        UserPoolId=UserPool_Id
    )

i = len(response["Users"])

while (i>0):
    #pour chaque utilisateur
    for user in response["Users"]:
        dicti["Users"] = {}
        dicti["Users"][i] = {}
        dicti["Users"][i]["UserName"]=user["Username"]

        time.sleep(1)
        response2 = client.admin_list_groups_for_user(
            Username=user["Username"],
            UserPoolId=UserPool_Id
        )

        List_Group_Name=list()
        for group in  response2["Groups"]:
            List_Group_Name.append(group["GroupName"])

        dicti["Users"][i]["GroupName"]=List_Group_Name
    i=i-1

return(dicti)
```

Comment: it didn't wok but i change it using a list of dictionary and it works thanks for your reactivity:

Answer (score 0):

#get a list of users
    try:
        response = client.list_users(
            UserPoolId=UserPool_Id,
        )
    except:
        print ("Error message")

```
response = client.list_users(
        UserPoolId=UserPool_Id
    )

List_Group_Users = list()
dictionnaire={}

#for each user get a list of the groups he belong
for user in response["Users"]:
    dictionnaire["UserName"]=user["Username"]


    #Rècupère la liste des groupe auquels appartient le user
    response2 = client.admin_list_groups_for_user(
        Username=user["Username"],
        UserPoolId=UserPool_Id
    )
    List_Group_Name=list()
    for group in  response2["Groups"]:
        List_Group_Name.append(group["GroupName"])

    dictionnaire["Groups"]=List_Group_Name

    List_Group_Users.append(dictionnaire)
    dictionnaire={}

return(List_Group_Users)
```